# How can I parse JSON data?

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

How can I parse this below JSON data as this data I am getting as a response back from the server and I want to extract the value and label from this json data and have to put on a popup window..

For example:-  For this data `"application_number":"20007524.8"`

I want to extract application_number as Application Number and corresponding to Application Number its value 20007524.8

Any suggestions how can I do this..

```
jsonp13082({"responseHeader":{"status":0,"Time":3,"params":{"json.wrf":"jsonp13082","wt":"json","q":"8377"}},"response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[{"key":"83779616","number":"080","name":"Designated","name":"Non ","number":"27837","date":"2010-08-24T07:00:00Z","name":"Canada","name":"Application","title":"collision detection","date":"2008-03-03T08:00:00Z","id":"414","code":"CA","date":"2009-03-03T08:00:00Z","name":"Michael Henry","mgr_name":"abc","id":"79616","name":"oen","claims":"74","date":"2012-03-03T08:00:00Z","claims":"8","url":"","inventors":["D.","rshi","Pa"],"guid":["23","26","25"],"towners":["XYZ"],"inventors":["D","name2","name3"],"owners":["XYZ"]}]}})
```

Comment: 1) Visit http://json.org 2) Select library 3) Profit. See [JSON Sans Eval](http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/) (extracted using step #1 from above).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a built in [`parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) function in jQuery.

**EDIT:** Example of usage:

```
// make a reference
var Obj = $.parseJSON('the json object');

alert(Obj.response.docs[0].c_application_number);
```

### How?

```
As you descend into the nodes, the name of the node goes on, so for example if you have a JSON object like this:

{
    "parent": {
        "sibling": "you found a sibling",
        "child": {
            "more_children": "hello"
        }
    }
}
```

Using the code like this:

```
var json = $.parseJSON('{ "parent": { "sibling": "you found a sibling", "child": { "more_children": "hello" } } }');

// I want to get the sibling value
alert(json.parent.sibling);

// I want to get the children value
alert(json.parent.child.more_children);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NarutoDevil/PgebV/).

Comment: @lolwut, As I am new to JSON parsing. Can you show me some example based on my data. That will be of great help for me..

Comment: @lolwut, thanks for the information.. But I am getting this JSON data in a data field so how can I write down this data field in $.parseJSON.. It should be like this  $.parseJSON('data');
or some other way??

Comment: No. Just use `$.parseJSON(data);`.

Comment: @lolwut, then I am getting 
jsonObj is null
[Break On This Error] alert(jsonObj.response.docs[0].c_application_number);

Comment: @lolwut, I am using this code  and data contains the actual response as JSON type.
var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(data);
alert(jsonObj.response.docs[0].c_application_number);

Comment: Could you try removing the content-type from the server side?